# How do I make an applescript that switches tabs one to the right

Tags: applescript

I have tried using the code;

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke 124 using {command down, option down}
end tell
```

is there anything wrong with this script because command option arrow normally switches tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tell application "Google Chrome" 
    activate 
end tell

tell application "System Events" 
    key code 124 using {command down, option down} 
end tell
```